# Why am I getting a "Could not find table 'users'" error?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm relatively new to Rails and I've been getting the above error whenever I'm testing my login page.
Here's the test view file:

```
<%= form_for :user, :url => create_path do |f| %>
  <p> Email: <br />  <%= f.text_field :email %></p>
  <p> Password: <br />  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Sign In", :disable_with => "Please wait...", :class => "btn primary" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Here's the Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController   
  before_filter :get_user, :except => [:register, :login, :create]
  before_filter :user_signed_in?, :only => [:delete]

  def create
    if user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email]).try(:authenticate, params[:user][:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path # Or whatever you want i.e. redirect_to user
    else
      render :new, :flash => { :error => "Bad email/password combination" }
    end
  end

  def delete
    session.delete(:user_id)
  end

  def register
    if Invite.find_by_hash(params[:hash]).blank?
      redirect_to root_path
      return
    end
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if(request.post? and @user.save)
      flash[:notice] = "Account Created Successfully"
      redirect_to root_path      
      return
    else
      flash.now[:warning] = @user.errors.full_messages
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def login

  end

  def get_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

And my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => {:minimum => 6}
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
  validates :name, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 32}
  validates :password, :presence => true, :length => {:minimum => 8}
  validates :username, :presence => true, :length => {:maximum => 20}, :uniqueness => true
  validates :blog, :uniqueness => true
  has_many :posts
end
```

The exact error I'm getting is this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#create
Could not find table 'users'
```

P.S.: I'm running Rails 3.1.0.rc8. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I can't seem to find any table. I just upgraded to Rails 3.1, everything was fine before that.

Comment: have you run the rake db:migrate command on the application root directory ?

Comment: Yea I have, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just upgraded to Rails 3.1 and everything was working before the upgrade, check your `database.yml` configuration. I doubt if the configuration has gone back to the defaults because of the upgrade.

If not, follow Rajkamal's suggestion and make sure you run the migrations.

Comment: I just checked my database.yml file and everything is exactly as it was before. Could it be that I'm using mysql instead of mysql2?

Comment: Yes.. Check your Gemfile and if you have installed the mysql2 gem, the adapter should be mysql2

Comment: I just changed mysql to mysql 2 in the Gemfile as well as the database.yml file and when running "bundle install" I got an error while it was installing mysql2 : `Installing mysql2 (0.3.7) with native extensions C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1
.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:552:in rescue in block in build_extensions: ERROR:
Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)` I was never able to install mysql2 on Windows. Maybe you could help?

Comment: I needed to specify some arguments when running: gem install mysql2.

Comment: Although now when I run db:create it just freezes there and never completes. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok well I fixed the db:create problem and I got the "could not find table" problem again :S help?

Comment: Please add your solution on how you solved the create problem so other people can refer to your question if they have the same issue. When you run rails dbconsole in CMD, and type `show tables;` do you see the tables it cannot find? Be sure your migrations are up to date as well via `rake db:migrate`