# Rake db:create doesn't end

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hey guys I recently installed mysql2 on Windows using this command: `gem install mysql2 -v 0.2.7` and added the mysql2 gem to my project's gemfile. I then ran bundle install with no problems, but when I try to do this command: `rake db:create -- trace` I get this:

```
 C:\rails_apps\app>rake db:create --trace
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
```

And then nothing happens. If anyone knows the solution, please tell me. Thanks.

P.S.: I'm running Rails 3.1.0.rc8

Here's my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: ***
  username: ***
  password: ***
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: ***
  username: ***
  password: ***
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: ***
  username: ***
  password: ***
  host: localhost
```

I only recently upgraded to Rails 3.1. Before that (on Rails 3.0) everything was working fine.

Comment: can you add your database.yml ?

Comment: @Awea Just added the database.yml file to the question.

Comment: Well nothing wrong in... it's strange you haven't any error message in your trace. You work in local ? Your mysql server is correctly launch ?

Comment: Yup I'm working locally, and how can I check if my mysql server is correctly launched? I can easily open up my mysql command line client and enter sql queries.

Comment: If it helps, I just upgraded from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1. Everything was working fine before Rails 3.1.

Comment: Can you just try rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development and what's your OS ?

Comment: @Awea I'm on Windows 7 and I just installed mysql2 version 0.3.7 instead of 0.2.7 and it seems that I can run rake db:migrate and rake db:create but for some reason the app can't any table. If you can help please check out my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253861/why-am-i-getting-a-could-not-find-table-users-error/7253953#7253953

Answer (score 0):

Go through this http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails-3-1.html It may be helpful for you.. What is your rake version?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try restart postgresql

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

2) If it not help try install Passenger

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-apache-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-with-passenger

doc http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Architectural%20overview.html#_overview

Hope it's help you

Answer (score -1):

do bundle install on this app folder